# HTML input pattern attribute

Tags: html

I'm want to take an input from user that is of the form "Z1C19999". So how i do set the pattern attribute.

I have tried using the following code.

```
<input type="text" name="farmercode" class="text" pattern="Z[1-3]+C[1-5]+[0-9]{5,8}" title="* Farmer's Lab Code can have only alphabets Z, C and digits between 0 and 9 in the format "Z1C19999" ">
```

The input must have the syntax Z[Any value between 1 to 3]C[Any value between 1 to 5][Any value between 0 to 9999]. The minimum length is 5 and max 8.

In my case even if I give 123456 only as input it is still accepting the value which is wrong. I want it to start with Z.

Comment: Please return and engage with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern works great in Chrome where I tested: see [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PgaEgr?editors=1100)

```css
input[pattern] ~ span {
  display: none;
}
input[pattern]:valid ~ span.valid {
  display: inline-block;
}
input[pattern]:invalid ~ span.invalid {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input
         type="text"
         name="farmercode"
         class="text"
         pattern="Z[1-3]+C[1-5]+[0-9]{5,8}"
         title="* Farmer's Lab Code can have only alphabets Z, C and digits between 0 and 9 in the format Z1C19999">
  <span class="valid">Valid</span>
  <span class="invalid">Invalid</span>
</form>
```

However, I think the RegExp that best describes your sentence is as follow

> The input must have the syntax Z[Any value between 1 to 3]C[Any value between 1 to 5][Any value between 0 to 9999]. The minimum length is 5 and max 8.

`Z[1-3]C[1-5][0-9]{5,8}`

Which leads me to the conclusion: What makes you think it doesn't work?

> TIP: Add the `required` attribute to force something inside.

Comment: The whole thing needs to be min 5 to max 8. See my answer

Comment: I see you are exasperated by this issue, so I'll help you understand it. Tell me which value work that shouldn't.